# Output only items from Column B to Column C when All 3 conditions are met in Column A

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-vlookup

I have two columns, one with account types (-A -B -C -D -E, etc) I only want Column B to be output into Column C if the account holder from Column B has all three account types (-A -B and -C)

**Objective:** Output Row from Column B into Column C IF Column A ends with -A, -B and -C

Here is what I have tried:

`=IF(RegExMatch(A2:A,"-A") AND (RegExMatch(A2:A,"-B") AND (RegExMatch(A2:A,"-C"),"$ColumnB","No Output")`

Clearly does not work and I am terrible with Google Sheets.

[image: utp]

Comment: If the criteria is true - do you want the output three times - in all rows containing AAA?

Answer (score 1):

### You can use [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) instead `REGEXP` and you can build your search string with [CONCATENATE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123?hl=en)

Sample:

```
=IF(AND(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(B2,"-A"), A$2:A, 1, false)<>"", VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(B2,"-B"), A$2:A, 1, false)<>"", VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(B2,"-C"), A$2:A, 1, false)<>""), B2, "No output")
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(LOWER(A2:A), LOWER("-a$|-b$|-c$")), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(.*)-"), ))
```

[image: 0]